# How to customize the background of the floating ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-actionmode

Under Marshmallow, we get ride of the top actionbar for the copy/past (thanks god) and we have instead a floating actionbar. My problem now is how to customize the background and text color of my floating Actionbar to be dark and not white (without changing the full theme of my app that is Theme.material.light.NoactionBar)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to do that. After long time digging into android source code I have found the toolbar implement with an android internal class **com.android.internal.widget.FloatingToolbar.FloatingToolbarPopup**.

The popup container is inflating from the layout named **com.android.internal.R.layout.floating_popup_container** which use this background **android:background="?attr/floatingToolbarPopupBackgroundDrawable"**.

It seem no way to set the attribute floatingToolbarPopupBackgroundDrawable from xml style.

However you can change the background from your activity class by using java reflection

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        try
        {
            Field field = mode.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFloatingToolbar");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object mFloatingToolbar = field.get(mode);
            field = mFloatingToolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object mPopup = field.get(mFloatingToolbar);
            field = mPopup.getClass().getDeclaredField("mContentContainer");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            ViewGroup mContentContainer = (ViewGroup)field.get(mPopup);
            mContentContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextComp‌​at.getColor(getActiv‌​ity(), R.color.yellow)));
```

Comment: what is fab? how and where to find it ? is it possible to do it in the styles.xml ?